# How to obtain data from database when using h:link and h:button in JSF GET method

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am having a simple application with one entity. The entity is Car so I have made CRUD methods and a "get all cars" method. I am using JSF to make a website where I have the list of cars with a edit/show/delete link next to it. Instead of using POST I want to use GET on the show/edit links. So far I have used the h:link with the id as a parameter and I set them in the show page as viewParams.

The whole application works but I have a question. Currently I am doing the EJB invocation that finds the appropiate car from the ID in the set-method for a car ID in the backing bean. I have not found another way of doing this so I wonder if this is correct? Because I don't have an action method that is invoked the same way as h:commandButton and return the string for the page that it shall navigate to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`<f:event type="preRenderView">`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html) to trigger a view action before the view is rendered.

E.g.

```html
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{cars.id}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{cars.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

with

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Cars {

    private Long id;
    private Car car;

    @EJB
    private CarService service;

    public void init() {
        car = service.find(id);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note that in upcoming JSF 2.2, the `<f:event type="preRenderView">` can be replaced by the new `<f:viewAction>` which is more self-documenting:

```html
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{cars.id}" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{cars.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)